# WCF is showing development machine path on production server

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I have deployed a wcf service app which I made on vs 2013, I published the project to a file system and moved the published version on production server. Now when I am accessing the service from production server it tries to connect to the local development machine where it says an exception

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Unable to connect to the remote server'. 


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, x-requested-with, origin, authorization, accept, client-security, X-PINGOTHER"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, OPTIONS "/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="3600"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="DAV, content-length, Allow"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ServiceWebApp.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceWebApp.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
      </webScriptEndpoint>

    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check endpoints you have exposed on prod server, it might be refering dev machine. Usually prod server and dev server reside on different domain network.

Comment: Did you check that the configuration file is pointing at the right servers?

Comment: there is no address giving to the endpoint.. I think it catches it from the location of your .svc file

Comment: which configuration file JB King, are you referring to the web.config file ?

Comment: Without seeing configs, its difficult to guess. Please post configs i.e. one containing WCF configurations like binding, service details etc

Comment: I have updated the question, added the config.

Comment: The web.config or app.config that would be used to store which server to use in each environment, assuming you use that instead of hard coded server names that would be my next thought.

Comment: there is no app.config, I only have web.config which I have pasted here.